# How can I allow users to duplicate a select field while creating a page from a custom content type?

Tags: nodes, entities

I have one select field (filled with taxonomy terms) in a custom content type. I can't figure out how to allow users to duplicate that select field (select "apples" and then add the select field again -- 2 instances of it now -- and select "oranges") when creating a page with the custom content type.

EDIT: is there perhaps a module that would do this? I've looked at similar kinds of modules like Webform, but none of them seem to be quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: do you just want to allow to select multiple terms when you add content? In that case you can just change the setting from for the term reference field to allow 2 or more values.

Comment: No, I noticed that. I want the users to be able to click a button like "Add another Fruit Type list" and a second (or third etc.) version of the same select box will appear.

Comment: I do not see any way to do so except to hide original multi-select and write some js/jquery widget to provide such impression.

Comment: Hmm... One of the reasons I was asking this was because I remember there (used?) to be a way to do that for certain fields -- I could define a long text field, and have the user duplicate that.

Comment: Yes, that is how most multi-value fields work, like textfields. Except taxonomy. It should be possible to write a field widget that does this, but it's no trivial to do that I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use CCk, you can just edit your field setting in it's global settings and select illimited value number : 
[image]
And you get a button "Add another" :
[image]
here I just used a text field for the example but it can be a select or anything else

Comment: Thanks! That does describe the process normally. In this case though, I was actually looking for a solution that worked with a taxonomy select box, as the normal solution doesn't appear to work with taxonomy-filled select boxes.

Comment: What module do you use for that??Maybe you can try [Content Taxonomy](http://drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy). I have not yet tried it but the description seems to be what you need

Comment: +1 -- it's great. Unfortunately, it still doesn't allow for multiple fields, but it does allow for multiple selecting, so it might work.

Comment: Ok that's a good beginning I think.

Comment: Alright. This doesn't work where taxonomy is used, but it did remind me how to do it, so I've accepted this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You ar welcome :)